# Irreale / unrealistische Wünsche

Tags: meaning, adjective

Haben die folgende Ausdrücke die gleiche Bedeutung? Ich habe bisher nur letzteren benutzt,  habe aber kürzlich den ersten in meinem Deutschkursbuch gefunden.

> Irreale Wünsche
>
> Unrealistische Wünsche

Die Wunschbeispiele unter dem Titel "Irreale Wünsche" im Buch sind:

> Ach, hätte ich doch ein größeres Auto!
>
> Ach, wäre meine Frau doch auch schon in Rente!

Comment: @swegi: Danke für die Korrektur!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aus dem Bauch heraus würde ich folgende Unterscheidung treffen.

**Unrealistischer Wunsch:**

> Ich möchte einen neuen Porsche kaufen.

**Irrealer Wunsch:**

> Ich möchte einen Porsche kaufen, der fliegen kann.

;-)

---

Die in der Frage erwähnten Beispiele sind de facto irreal, weil sie nicht der Realität entsprechen.

> Ach, hätte ich doch ein größeres Auto! ⇒ Ich habe ein kleines Auto.

D.h. sein/ihr Wunsch ist eine nicht der Realität entsprechender (irrealer) Wunsch. Ebenso hier:

> Ach, wäre meine Frau doch auch schon in Rente! ⇒ Meine Frau arbeitet noch.

Comment: Aha, das sieht sinnvoll aus. Die Wünsche vom Buch sind aber nicht so irreale; ich habe meine Frage ergänzt.

Comment: Achso. Sind diese Wünsche beide irreale und unrealistische?

Comment: @Tim Ja, meiner Meinung nach gibt es im grammatikalischen Sinn keinen Unterschied.

Comment: Mein Bauch sagte das gleiche ;-)